# I am three, but which one am I?

Tags: riddle

This is a puzzle i came up with earlier, with a few amendments. Work out what the three clues are, and then use the final clue to decide which one is the correct one.

> I am three things, but which one am I?
>
> 1: The internal temperature North, maybe a half more, and eleven elevens towards apollo's destination. I am almost modest, but not quite there.
>
> 2: I am the first of many, the largest and the brightest, but still small in the scale of things; I fit inside a belt.
>
> 3: I am plentiful harvest, but the sides of skulls no longer echo my name. Some even use an alternate name.
>
> Of these three, I am one, the one whose period is 1680

**I will only accept an answer that fits all of the clues and explains them. Good luck ;)**

Comment: (Whoops, my bad! Didn't realize this was posted pre-sandbox. Sorry about that!)

Comment: I didn't realise the sandbox was such a recent thing... Turns out the post was only made 20 hours ago!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you:

(Credit goes to @Ivanhoe for the clarification of clue 2)

> Ceres, asteroid

The internal temperature North, maybe a half more, and eleven elevens towards apollo's destination. I am almost modest, but not quite there.

> Looks like coordinates: 37.5 (or 36.5) north. 121 towards apollo, god of the sun. The sun heads west, so 121 W. At this coordinates there is a city Modesto and there is (not quite there) a nearby city Ceres.

I am the first of many, the largest and the brightest, but still small in the scale of things: I fit inside a belt.

> Ceres is the largest object in the asteroid belt that lies between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter

I am plentiful harvest, but the sides of skulls no longer echo my name. Some even use an alternate name.

> Demeter or Ceres is the Goddess of the Harvest. Sides of skulls, i.e. temples - Ceres is a Roman goddess and is not worshiped any longer

Of these three, I am one, the one whose period is 1680

> It's orbital period is 1680 days

Comment: I thought it was ceres but I couldn't done with the explanation.

Comment: Maybe the second which shows something about asteroid belt. @Radoslav

Comment: You need to show that it fits all three clues for it to be accepted.

Comment: @AricFowler I'm working on it.

Comment: The correct answer to no. 2 is that Ceres is the largest object (and possibly the brightest) in the asteroid belt situated between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter

Comment: "towards the moon"... which apollo are you referring to? there are many people, spacecraft, space objects, companies and films names 'Apollo', aswell as the god of course

Comment: @AricFowler Got it! Check my update.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov I wasn't expecting you to get the coordinates one but well done!

Answer (score 4):

Could it be:

> Alnitak, the first star (it's a **triple** star system in fact) in Orion's **belt**

I am three things, but which one am I?

> Alnitak is a triple star system

I am the first of many, the largest and the brightest, but still small in the scale of things: I fit inside a belt.

> Alnitak Aa, the first star in the aforementioned triple system, is the brightest star of class O in the sky and it fits inside a belt

The other clues still elude me so far.

Comment: You need to show that it fits all three clues for it to be accepted.

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board.

Comment: This was my thought as well but Alnitak's orbit period is only 1500 years

Comment: @Separatrix I know but I figured it was worth a shot to know if I'm on the correct path or not

Answer (score 2):

> Comet

Of these three, i am one, the one whose period is 1680

> Great comet of 1680

I am the first of many, the largest and the brightest, but still small in the scale of things as i fit inside a belt.

> oort cloud

The internal temperature North, maybe a half more, and eleven elevens towards apollo's destination. I am almost modest, but not quite there.

> North = north pole? Comets are usually icy

Comment: You need to show that it fits all three clues for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Johann Sebastian Bach

since:

> I am the first of many, the largest and the brightest, but still small
>   in the scale of things: I fit inside a belt.

and:

> Of these three, I am one, the one whose period is 1680

would fit. But no clue on the other two

Comment: How does Johann Sebastian Bach fit inside a belt?

Comment: I think most humans fit inside a belt.. or not?

Comment: @Paagalpan By wearing one?

Comment: Haha ok. Sorry. I misunderstood it.

Comment: You need to prove it fits all three clues for the answer to be accepted.