# I am five, but which one am I?

Tags: riddle

This riddle follows the same format as my previous puzzle [I am three, but which one am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/i-am-three-but-which-one-am-i).

In this puzzle each clue has an answer, all of which share the same name. You must find something which answers all five clues and then use the final clue to work out which is correct. Lets go!

> I am five, but which one am I?
>
> 1: The next generation knows me. I am two parts as a whole, a piece of the seventh act of adding herbs.
>
> 2: 63 to 67, i am knowledge from above, created by the settlers. I am an alternative for Corona.
>
> 3: Originally born in Japan, i was carried to New Orleans. I was renamed after a Philistine warrior, defeated by the future king of Israel.
>
> 4: I hope to sacrifice a friend. I begin with QB4.
>
> 5: I remember photons even before I am fully developed. People saw me in 1966, 2012, and 2016
>
> Of these five, I am one. The one used by two Ks in 86.

**I will only accept an answer that fits all of the clues and explains them, but feel free to post part-solutions and bounce ideas.**

Good luck ;)

Comment: I feel like i made this one too difficult... I might add _a little bit_ more detail to the clues if noone gets it in the next hour

Comment: I've got a bunch of ideas...

Comment: (but so far they are not leading to the same answer for each of the five things...)

Comment: (which makes me suspect I may be misunderstanding something)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You are allowed to post part-solutions if you want

Comment: Yes, I know, but I prefer to make more progress than I have so far.

Comment: fair enough. To be honest though, once you have one solved the others are easy. You just need to make sure it fits all of the clues.

Comment: The trouble is that I have obviously correct answers to #3 and #4 but they are not the same answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I'm sure there will be more coming soon!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain So does my post in the sandbox need 10 upvotes for this to be re-opened? I just made a sandbox post in response to this. I also removed the [riddle] tag since this isn't actually a riddle; it is a series of cryptic clues.

Comment: @AricFowler Yes, that's how it works. This still sounds like a riddle to me, whether it had the tag or not. You're trying to get people to identify something based on provided clues, which is basically the definition of a riddle.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain in that case i'll wait. Do you have to sandbox every riddle you post on the site?

Comment: @Aric: Yes, every riddle must be sandboxed. Also, [cryptic-clues] is for clues in the style of a cryptic crossword. Please read tag wikis before using them.

Comment: @Deusovi what tags do you suggest then?

Comment: Looks like a [riddle] to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so the answer is

> Queen's Gambit, chess opening.

1. The next generation knows me. I am two parts as a whole, a piece of the seventh act of adding herbs.

> Haven't worked this one out yet. [EDITED to add:] But Anthony Geoghegan has got it: it's a Star Trek reference. See his answer for the details.

2. 63 to 67, i am knowledge from above, created by the settlers. I am an alternative for Corona.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KH-7_Gambit, a reconnaissance satellite from the United States. It had a predecessor called Corona.

3. Originally born in Japan, i was carried to New Orleans. I was renamed after a Philistine warrior, defeated by the future king of Israel.

> This is Goliath (an amusement park ride brought from Japan to New Orleans and later to Texas) -- which, as I completely failed to notice but Anthony Geoghegan points out in comments, was actually originally called "Gambit".

4. I hope to sacrifice a friend. I begin with QB4.

> The Queen's Gambit in chess. (It begins with Q4 rather than QB4, but it's moving the pawn to QB4 that makes the opening the QG rather than something else. Usually black actually declines the gambit.)

5. I remember photons even before I am fully developed. People saw me in 1966, 2012, and 2016

> Refers to photographic film, which records photons before it is developed to make the record visible. There were movies called "Gambit" in 1966, 2012, and 2016 (though the 2016 one was about something different from the 1966 and 2012 ones).

Of these five, I am one. The one used by two Ks in 86.

> This must surely be the QG, used tremendously often in chess matches and in particular played by both sides in the world championship match between Karpov and Kasparov in 1986.

Comment: changed 4th clue back to original.

Comment: OK! (For what it's worth, the original seemed clear enough to me.)

Comment: They *did* share the same name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath_(Six_Flags_Fiesta_Texas)#Thrill_Valley_.281995.E2.80.942002.29)

Comment: Only three clues left to guess then

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Ayyyy got that one.

Comment: Oh, well spotted!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan about number five... nope. It is the completely boring and uninteresting answer!

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll fill in the details a bit more clearly. I think we're done now, then.

Comment: Well done on 5. I had been thinking of photo-sensitive chemicals but couldn't make any relevant connections.

Comment: I think #5 isn't 100% convincing, but I have the original questioner's confirmation that it's what was intended :-).

Answer (score 3):

I could only solve 1 and 2 and Gareth already posted the answer to 3 so here is my partial solution:

1: The next generation knows me. I am two parts as a whole, a piece of the seventh act of adding herbs.

> This refers to Episodes 4 and 5 (two parts of a whole) of Season 7 (seasoning being the act of adding spices and herbs to a dish) of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, titled Gambit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_(Star_Trek%3A_The_Next_Generation)

---

Edit: I figured out 2 (but Gareth beat me to it):

2. 63 to 67, i am knowledge from above, created by the settlers. I am an alternative for Corona

> Satellites provide information from above (lower earth orbit). CORONA was the codename for a satellite reconnaissance program run by the CIA from the late 50s to the early 70s.  From 1963 to 1967, the GAMBIT satellite program was run by the US Air Force for similar purposes: http://nsarchive.gwu.edu/NSAEBB/NSAEBB186/

Comment: I answered 2 too. But I didn't have #1. Good catch!